# conditional dynamic dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, microsoft-forms

I would like to create a microsoft form (i already read online that such a situation is not possible to build in google forms) which has two dropdown.

Dropdown1 values = {A,B,C,D,E,F,AA,AB,AD,AF}

Dropdown2 values =Dropdown 1 values - {user selected value from dropdown 1}

Essentially the values in the dropdown2 should not contain the user selected values from dropdown 1.

I am sorry if it is already answered (could you point the link to me?). But I am not sure what the technical word is for such situations. Is it a dynamic dropdown? or conditional dropdowns?
Also is it possible to do it in microsoft forms or powerapps?

Answer (score 0):

We can not have the cascading/interdependent dropdown in Microsoft Forms.

You can build the same using PowerApps.

[Create dependent drop-down lists in a canvas app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/dependent-drop-down-lists)

You take two drop-down control. Store your choices in the collection named col1 and assign it as a data source to your first dropdown.

On Selection of the value in the first dropdown, write the logic to generate a new collection named col2 which will have all the choices except from the selected one in the first dropdown in the OnSelect property of the first dropdown.

Assing the col2 as a data source to your second dropdown.